# How to find difference of array elements in groovy?

Tags: groovy, maps, jenkins-groovy, difference

How to find difference of array elements that are maps in groovy?

```
def first = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], 
['fruit':'apple', 'drink':'milk']]

def second = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], 
['fruit':'melon', 'drink':'milk'],
['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]

def diff = first.minus(second)

echo "diff ${diff}
```

Actual output is

```
diff []
```

Expected output is

```
[['fruit':'melon'],['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my end,

```
def first = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], ['fruit':'apple', 'drink':'milk']] 
def second = [['fruit':'grapes','drink':'tea'],
['fruit':'melon', 'drink':'milk'], ['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]

def firstDiff = first.findAll { !second.contains(it) }
def secondDiff = second.findAll { !first.contains(it) }

println(firstDiff);
println(secondDiff);
```

The output:

```
['fruit':'apple', 'drink':'milk']
[['fruit':'melon', 'drink':'milk'],['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have when you want to do this and find the diff is - which array do you prioritize when you compare the elements? Given your original question, it looks like you prioritize the bigger one as the `fruit` is `melon` in your required output (but could've been `apple`).

Considering this, here is the solution I've created for you which prioritises the bigger array (You can test it here as well http://tpcg.io/03UE84):

```
def first = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], 
['fruit':'apple', 'drink':'milk']]

def second = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], 
['fruit':'melon', 'drink':'milk'],
['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]

def diff = []

def biggerArray
def smallerArray

if ( first.size() > second.size() ) {
    biggerArray = first;
    smallerArray = second;
}
else if ( first.size() < second.size() ) {
    biggerArray = second;
    smallerArray = first;
}
else {
    //You have to decide how the diff looks in case they are the same size
}

for ( i = 0; i < biggerArray.size(); i++ ) {
    if ( smallerArray[i] && smallerArray[i] != biggerArray[i] ) {
        def pair = [:]
        if ( smallerArray[i].get("fruit") != biggerArray[i].get("fruit") ) {
            pair["fruit"] = biggerArray[i].get("fruit");
        }
        
        if ( smallerArray[i].get("drink") != biggerArray[i].get("drink") ) {
            pair["drink"] = biggerArray[i].get("drink");
        }
        
        if ( !pair.isEmpty ) {
            diff.add(pair);
        }
    }
    else if ( !smallerArray[i] ) {
        diff.add(biggerArray[i]);
    }
}

println(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried your code in groovysh and got something close to the answer you were looking for:

```
def first = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], 
            ['fruit':'apple', 'drink':'milk']]
def second = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'], 
             ['fruit':'melon', 'drink':'milk'],
             ['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]
println( first.minus(second) )
println( second.minus(first) )
```

Output:

```
 [[fruit:apple, drink:milk]]
 [[fruit:melon, drink:milk], [fruit:coconut, drink:soda]]
```

The `minus` method is going to be order dependent.  It won't return items in the second list that aren't in the first.  It's only going to return the items that are only in the first list.  So 'melon', 'coconut' aren't going to show up with `first.minus(second)`.  Of course the obvious issue is that `drink: milk` shows up because it is contained within maps where 1 member isn't in the first so it includes all members of that map.  That's just how `minus` method works so it can't be a solution.

So here is another method that does what you expect (but it's still order dependent):

```
def first = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'],
             ['fruit':'apple', 'drink':'milk']]
def second = [['fruit':'grapes', 'drink':'tea'],
              ['fruit':'melon', 'drink':'milk'],
              ['fruit':'coconut', 'drink':'soda']]

def diff( srcA, srcB ) {
    srcA.findResults { item ->
       def out = item.findAll { x ->
         !srcB.find { y -> y.containsKey(x.key) && y[x.key] == x.value }
       }
       out ?: null
    }
}

println( "first diff second = ${diff( first, second )}" )
println( "second diff first = ${diff( second, first )}" )
```

Output:

```
first diff second = [[fruit:apple]]
second diff first = [[fruit:melon], [fruit:coconut, drink:soda]]
```